# server network fails when starting k3s server

Tags: linux, networking, k3s

We have a k3s cluster in our staging environment with one master and two agents. Recently, I noticed that the master node was using high resources. I was also unable to SSH to the server from our terminal. I had to use our IAAS to access it and found that someone had made the master node schedulable. I drained the master node and rebooted it, but still couldn't SSH to the node. Additionally, the agent nodes couldn't connect to the master.

I disabled the k3s service, and everything worked fine. However, after starting k3s, I was again unable to SSH or ping the node after a few seconds. Old connections worked fine, but new connections failed. For example, if I had an SSH session before starting k3s, it continued to work after starting it. I could ping localhost on the node, but I couldn't ping the IP we used for it. The node has a private IP address.

I ruled out resource issues as the CPU usage on the node after draining was around one percent. I set a CPUQuota in its system file to be sure, but nothing changed.

The k3s version is v1.26.5+k3s1, and the k3s service start command is as follows (node name and IP omitted):

```
/usr/local/bin/k3s \
    server \
        '--node-external-ip' \
        'IP' \
        '--node-name' \
        'NODE_NAME' \
        '--disable=traefik' \
        '--node-ip' \
        'IP' \
        '--flannel-backend=host-gw' \
        '--kube-proxy-arg=proxy-mode=ipvs' \
```

```
root@localhost:/home/devbale# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I also checked with `ip a` to see if interface ip changes but it was still there.
when I ping the IP after k3s start I get `Destination Port Unreachable`.
agent nodes get `connection reset by peer` when they try to connect to the master.

there is no firewalld on the node, UFW is disabled and `iptables -l` returned no rule.

I couldn't find any useful logs for k3s. If you need to know anything else, please let me know. I searched for a solution to this problem, but I haven't found anything yet. Thanks for your help.

I couldn't find any useful logs for k3s, but if you need to know anything, please let me know.

I have searched for a solution to this problem, but haven't found anything. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome! If you have conducted a search and found no satisfactory results, could you please cite the websites you visited and explain why they didn't help you? Additionally, could you provide information on how the iptables looked before and after starting the service?

Comment: thanks. sure. most of my results were irrelevant and the problems were caused by a firewall or lack of resources but here are some results: https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/issues/556 https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/issues/60 (I think first one may have some relevance but couldn't figure what to do). I added the iptables output in question, there were not any changes to it after I started k3s.

Comment: please always use the question by editing, to keep the comments section clear